PromQL join with identical label value but different label name
I am trying to combine 2 metrics in a promQL query using the Grafana example here:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/monitor-infrastructure/monitor-cloud-provider/aws/cloudwatch-metrics/query-tag-data/
The issue I have using the example:
( aws_certificatemanager_days_to_expiry_average + on (name) group_left(tag_Name) aws_certificatemanager_info )

Is that the labels for the AWS ARN where I want to join are different named in the metrics.
So aws_certificatemanager_days_to_expiry_average contains:
{__name__="aws_certificatemanager_days_to_expiry_average", account_id="xxx", dimension_CertificateArn="arn:aws:acm:xxx:xxx:certificate/GUID"}

and aws_certificatemanager_info contains:
{__name__="aws_certificatemanager_info", account_id="xxxx", name="arn:aws:acm:xxx:xxx:certificate/GUID", tag_Name="the-friendly-name-i-need"}

I am struggling with the label_replace function since I am pretty sure it's what I need. The answer here also suggests it: Promql join on different label names
But cant find a good example (yet) how to combine it in a single query.

Found it:
label_replace(aws_certificatemanager_days_to_expiry_average, "name", "$1", "dimension_CertificateArn", "(.*)") + on(name) group_left(tag_Name) aws_certificatemanager_info

Found it and sharing for future like-minded:
label_replace(aws_certificatemanager_days_to_expiry_average, "name", "$1", "dimension_CertificateArn", "(.*)") + on(name) group_left(tag_Name) aws_certificatemanager_info


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
